# Python get query from MySQL, remove the string format

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently using an example to select a variable from MySQL via Python. For this I'm using the MySQLdb import.

It all works great, I'm able to get the value from MySQL but when I print the result, it returns as:

```
('text',)
```

Is there a way to get this to just show up as

```
text
```

The code I'm working with is:

```
try:
        cursor.execute("""SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name='text'""")
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        print results
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 :

```
print(results[0])
```

Python 2 :

```
print results[0]
```

This will take the first and only element of the tuple, which is `'text'`, and printing a string will just write `text` without quotes in the console.